# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework' in the config of a different solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, config, .net-2.0

I have multiple solutions sitting side by side on my machine, for different applications.  Working on one .NET 2.0 Windows Forms application it started to throw an exception when it had previously run fine.  It was an "Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'" parser error.

I checked the config of the application I was working on and it has no targetFramework element.  Looking at the error message more closely I saw that it specifies the config as being from another solution entirely, a responsive website.  I didn't have that web project running, nor do I have a web application set up for it in IIS on my local machine.  The application I'm working on has no reference to the web application in either the config file or anywhere.

Any ideas for getting round this problem, short of deleting the web application solution from my machine?  I'm at a loss.

Note that the web application targets .NET 4.5 while the application I'm currently working on targets .NET 2.0.

**EDIT:** I decided to delete the web application and the folder it's in but I'm still getting the same error.  In addition, when I open IIS Manager and try to look at any feature for any web site (eg when I click on the Authentication feature for a website in IIS Manager) that is set up on my machine I get a similar error:

```
There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:

Filename:

\\?\C:\Working\OrderTracker\OrderTrackerWebService\web.config

Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

That path, excluding the leading `\\?\`, was the path to the web.config of the web application I deleted.

As I previously mentioned, the web application I deleted did not appear to be set up in IIS at the time I deleted it.  Perhaps it was in the past, I can't remember.

I'm using IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1.

**EDIT 2, THE FIX:** (not sure of the etiquette of answering my own question but I thought the fix might be useful to others in future)  It turned out the problem was the configuration of the default website in IIS Manager.  It was set to `C:\Working\OrderTracker\OrderTrackerWebService`  Setting it back to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` solved the two problems (error when looking at the configuration of web applications in IIS Manager, and the original "Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'" error when running the desktop application).

Comment: What is the target framework of the associated application pool for that site. Does it match up with the web app?

Comment: The web app has not been set up in IIS.  It doesn't have an associated app pool.

Comment: If you go to the project properties -> Web, where is it setting up the project  when you build it?

Comment: @AshwinNair: Please see the edit to my question.